# Admission into masters degree without partial or full transcript

Tags: masters

I'm in a last year of my bachelor degree of science in wildlife management that will be completed in July this year, 2016 at Sokoine university of Agriculture (SUA) in Tanzania. I would like to continue with masters degree especially outside the country but I would like to know if it is possible to apply abroad and scholarships without having either full or partial transcripts because for the time being they will not be already released and if it will it is only partial transcript that can be available on around May this year.

Answer (score 6):

It should be fine; we're aware of the disparity between our application deadlines and your graduation dates. When you graduate you'll likely have your grad-school acceptance (here's hoping!) and you'll have to send an official transcript to that school to confirm your degree.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly apply with partial/non-official transcripts, adding a letter (hopefully official from your school) explaining the situation. Just make sure to be able to get as full a picture of your grades as possible, the place you are applying to really want complete data that also can be verified.